# Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am making a call to REST URL and trying to measure how much time it is taking to get the response back.

I am using `DefaultHttpClient` for that to get the response back from `REST URL`.

In my below program , each thread will be working on a particular range. Like Each Thread will work between `1 - 100` and second thread will work between `101 - 200` etc.

SO in my below code, for the first time it works fine. But for the second time, it is throwing exception on this line `httpclient.execute` for the second time as-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing here?-

Below is my code-

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private HttpGet httpGet;
    private HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            httpGet = new HttpGet(
                    "http://localhost:8080/service/BEService/v1/get/USERID=10000/profile.ACCOUNT.SERVICE
            httpGet.getRequestLine();

            for (int userId = id; userId < id + noOfTasks; userId++) {

                    long start = System.nanoTime();

                    response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

                    long end = System.nanoTime() - start;
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Threw a Exception in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated Code:-**

If I am doing it something like this-

```
class Task implements Runnable {

    private DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private HttpGet httpGet;
    private HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            for (int userId = id; userId < id + noOfTasks; userId++) {

                httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/service/BEService/v1/get/USERID=10000/profile.ACCOUNT.SERVICE");
                httpGet.getRequestLine();

                long start = System.nanoTime();

                response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

                long end = System.nanoTime() - start;

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Threw a Exception in " + getClass().getSimpleName(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

then it is fine or not?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Is there anything wrong I am doing here?

Yes. As stated in [the docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e619):

> BasicClientConnectionManager is a simple connection manager that
>   maintains only one connection at a time. Even though this class is
>   thread-safe it ought to be used by one execution thread only.
>   BasicClientConnectionManager will make an effort to reuse the
>   connection for subsequent requests with the same route. It will,
>   however, close the existing connection and re-open it for the given
>   route, if the route of the persistent connection does not match that
>   of the connection request. If the connection has been already been
>   allocated, then java.lang.IllegalStateException is thrown.
>
> BasicClientConnectionManager is used by HttpClient per default.

See ["Multithreaded request execution"](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e639) on how to use a [pooling connection manager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e627) that can handle requests across multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for the suggestion. I have updated the code with the changes. If I am doing it like this then I will be having any problem?

Comment: It's hard to say from the snippets you've shown. It sounds like you have an HttpClient crossing over threads, which isn't allowed with the basic connection manager. I suppose it could also be that you didn't properly [release the low-level resources](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e139) in the first case.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but in his code the httpClient is not shared. In C# a thread is a method but in Java it's the whole class (jj09.net/multithreading-csharp-vs-java). So yes the problem is the resource release (https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/x/9gFqAQ , https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#consume(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)).

Comment: @RyanStewart The links are broken

Answer (score 44):

Assuming you are using the vanilla `DefaultHttpClient` (which uses `BasicClientConnectionManager` internally), you first need to consume the outstanding/last response.

`EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(httpResponse.getEntity());`

Else, you can reallocate `DefaultHttpClient` each time.

Else, you can wrap the `execute()` plus `EntityUtils.consumeQuietly()` inside a `synchronized()` block to prevent multi-threading bugs.

Source: [Workaround to not shutdown DefaultHttpClient() each time after usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728683/workaround-to-not-shutdown-defaulthttpclient-each-time-after-usage)

Comment: First ensure only a single thread use DefaultHttpClient;then for every execute,do not forget httpResponse.getEntity().It will be ok.

Comment: The first advice is strong. The second isn't, because reallocating Http client isntances are not cheap

Answer (score 1):

This is my configuration for RestTemplate using pool connection manager. It works very well in 5 more concurrent threads.

```
<!-- RestTemplate -->
<beans:bean id="restTemplateYT" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="httpRequestFactoryYT" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="httpRequestFactoryYT" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"> 
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager"/>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="connectTimeout" value="5000" />
</beans:bean>
```

Spring version: 3.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The RestTemplate with a HttpClientConnectionManager implemented by the BasicHttpClientConnectionManager factory can be interrupted by IllegalStateException with error message: 'Connection [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] is still allocated'.
Instead, you need to use the HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory implementation.

Attached code example with spring boot 3.2 version that reproduces the IllegalStateException when using the BasicHttpClientConnectionManager implementation, along with the fix using the HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.ConnectionConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.io.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.hc.core5.util.Timeout;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, classes = RestTemplateConnectionManagerApplication.class)
class RestTemplateConnectionManagerApplicationTests {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestTemplateConnectionManagerApplication.class);
    private static final String localhost = "http://localhost:";

    @Value("${spring.server.port}")
    private Integer serverPort;

//    @Autowired
//    @Qualifier("restTemplateWithBasicPoolManager")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);

    @Test
    void restTemplateWithBasicHttpClientConnectionManagerIllegalStateExceptionTest() {
        initRestTemplateWithHttpClientConnectionManager();
        assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
            ScheduledFuture<List<Future<String>>> schedule = executorService.schedule(this::sendReq, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            assertResponse(schedule);
        }).hasCauseInstanceOf(IllegalStateException.class)
                .hasMessageContaining("Connection [Not bound] is still allocated");
    }

    @Test
    void restTemplateWithPoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerTest() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        initRestTemplateWithPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        ScheduledFuture<List<Future<String>>> schedule = executorService.schedule(this::sendReq, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertResponse(schedule);
    }


    @Test
    void restTemplateWithDefaultPoolManagerTest() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        initRestTemplateWithDefaultPoolManager();
        ScheduledFuture<List<Future<String>>> schedule = executorService.schedule(this::sendReq, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        assertResponse(schedule);
    }

    private void initRestTemplateWithDefaultPoolManager() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .build();
    }

    private void initRestTemplateWithPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultConnectionConfig(createConnectionConfig())
                .setMaxConnTotal(100)
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(20)
                .build();
        HttpClient httpClient = buildHttpClient(connectionManager);
        initRestTemplateWithHttpClientConnectionManager(httpClient);
    }

    private void initRestTemplateWithHttpClientConnectionManager(HttpClient httpClient) {
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

    private void initRestTemplateWithHttpClientConnectionManager() {
        BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setConnectionConfig(createConnectionConfig());
        HttpClient httpClient = buildHttpClient(connectionManager);
        initRestTemplateWithHttpClientConnectionManager(httpClient);
    }

    private static HttpClient buildHttpClient(HttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager) {
        return HttpClientBuilder
                .create()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .build();
    }

    private ConnectionConfig createConnectionConfig() {
        return ConnectionConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(Timeout.of(Duration.ofMillis(0)))// timeout to get connection from pool
                .setSocketTimeout(Timeout.of(Duration.ofSeconds(5))) // standard connection timeout
                .build();
    }

    private List<Future<String>> sendReq() {
        return IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(index -> executorService.submit(() -> {
            logger.info("sending request");
            return restTemplate.getForObject(localhost + serverPort + "/", String.class);
        })).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static void assertResponse(ScheduledFuture<List<Future<String>>> schedule) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        for (Future<?> future : schedule.get()) {
            assertThat(future.get()).isEqualTo("ok");
        }
    }

}
```

Controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ExampleController {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ExampleController.class);

    @GetMapping()
    public String restTemplateTimeOut() {
        logger.info("ok");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Duration.ofMillis(200).toMillis());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return "ok";
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```