# Is this the right way to use AIMDBackoffManager to instantiate HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, solr4

**Background :**

1. I am using HttpClient (SolrJ) to connect to a Solr service. The question is not directly related to Solr though.
2. I bumped into the following issue when doing a Load testing.

   *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.*
3. SOF Answer - to use Pooled connection manager

   [Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866362/invalid-use-of-basicclientconnmanager-connection-still-allocated)

**Question :**

I am using the [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager.html) as in the following code. Instead of manually throttling the connection size, I would like it to be managed using the [AIMDBackoffManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AIMDBackoffManager.html).  However, I see that the `AIMDBackoffManager` needs the connection pool as its parameter.

```
public static final PoolingClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();

public static DefaultHttpClient getHttpClient(){

    DefaultHttpClient  httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(poolingConnectionManager);
    httpClient.setBackoffManager(new AIMDBackoffManager(poolingConnectionManager));

 ...
 ...
```

}

I googled a fair bit but I am unable to find any examples on the usage of `BackoffManager`. So, this is what I did but I am not excited in passing the connection manager twice to the `DefaultHttpClient`.  Or should I not be worried considering the first time I am passing it to the `HttpClient` and the second time I am passing it to the `BackoffManager`?

I am using httpclient-4.2.3

Answer (score 1):

I ventured into this deep water as well. I have been investigating how to use ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy which seems failing due to BackoffManager in my case. I have an impression that this is not a finished functionality as I can't google out its usage and there is not much in the HttpClient source code either.

Comment: Agreed @Peter. There's not much help on the web for this.

Comment: The original contributor of that feature never got around to fully completing and documenting it. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1101. We will happily take PRs with improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The AIMDBackoffManager constructor takes a [ConnPoolControl](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/pool/ConnPoolControl.html) (which the connection manager implements). Looking at this interface you'll see it only returns route-specific statistics of the pool which is what the BackoffManager uses to perform its tasks.

So you should not be worried about passing the connection manager twice while building the client, just be aware that AIMDBackoffManager acquires a lock on the connection manager in its backOff and probe implementations, which you can see in the [source](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/22902593e78d56423709b66abf4757082ddced50/httpclient5/src/main/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/AIMDBackoffManager.java).